# MySQL returns wrong result on PHP search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my MySQL query which ignores category field condition, the result also returns results from other category which are not mentioned in the query, here is my mysql query statement

```
select *,classifieds.id as id 
from classifieds,classifieds_meta 
where 
    category=1 
    AND meta_key='vehicle_make' 
    and meta_value=2 
    OR meta_key='vehicle_make' 
    and meta_value=3 
    AND (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=9) 
    OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=10) 
    OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=11) 
    AND classifieds.id=classifieds_meta.classifieds_id 
GROUP BY classifieds.id
```

the above sql statement returns result from category 1 and 6 instead just 1, can someone please help on this?

Comment: You are selecting `*` which will select all from both tables.  If you only want all from classifieds, you should use `classifieds.*`

Comment: You're mixing `and` and `or` clauses, which will DEFINITELY lead to incorect results, unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing and understand mysql's operator precedence rules: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Comment: Or just wrap everything after `where category=1 AND` in parenthesis so that it is evaluated seperately from the `category=1`.

Comment: now i have improved the code like this but still no luck, here is my code select *,classifieds.id as id from classifieds,classifieds_meta where category=1 AND (meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value=2) OR (meta_key='vehicle_make' and meta_value=3) AND (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=9) OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=10) OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=11) AND classifieds.id=classifieds_meta.classifieds_id GROUP BY classifieds.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add parentheses in the WHERE clause. **AND** has higher precedence than **OR** (visit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html):

```
select *,classifieds.id as id 
from classifieds,classifieds_meta 
where
    category=1 AND (
        meta_key='vehicle_make' 
        and meta_value=2 
        OR meta_key='vehicle_make' 
        and meta_value=3 
        AND (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=9) 
        OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=10) 
        OR (meta_key='vehicle_mileage' and meta_value=11) 
        AND classifieds.id=classifieds_meta.classifieds_id
    )
GROUP BY classifieds.id
```

If this is in the WHERE clause for example

```
WHERE row1=1 AND row2=2 OR row3=3

--equal to
WHERE (row1=1 AND row2=2) OR row3=3
```

When row3 equals 3 then row1 could be anything - this is your case.

Comment: Add some more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 groups of conditions connected by OR operator and only first group has 'category=1' condition. You need more brackets if you want get ONLY from first category. Like

```
where category=1 AND (rest of conditions)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an order of precedence in the **`AND`** and **`OR`** boolean operations.

Consider:

```
false AND ( false OR true )   => false
```

vs.

```
( false AND false ) OR true   => true
```

MySQL is *not* indeterminate when you specify

```
false AND false OR true
```

MySQL has a specific order of precedence, we are guaranteed whether the AND or the OR will be evaluated first.

We can use parens to **specify** the order that MySQL should evaluate the operations.